# Has anyone every done any integration with the M.A.M.E. arcade ROM emulator?

Tags: emulation

I'm looking to write an application that will grab some basic information from the MAME emulator.

I was wondering if anyone on here had an experience with that. I've done a little searching and can't seem to find much information.

I'm hoping to just make a few hooks into the running emulator to find out things like when a game starts, what game starts, how many players, when the player stops playing, game scores, etc.

Has anyone ever heard of this being done? I have no idea how much of this is really possible, but I'm looking to explore the possibilities here and any pointers would be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

building mame from sources is definitely doable, and as a result modifying those sources and building is doable.  Adding hooks so that an application can simply monitor what is going on in a particular game in mame is probably the easier task, creating some sort of app to app communication and having the new app monitor that information.  Mame may very well have these sorts of things build in as there are some or at least one gui launcher for mame.